# React Context variable not in sync in interval function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, react-context

I have a spotifyPlayer variable which I get from Context API. It has property `spotifyPlayer.playback.position` which is a number which updates on it's own. I'm able to display this property in component and when it updates the component updates too, I have no problems with it. But I want to create a `localPosition` state which would on interval update it's value by some number and when the `spotifyPlayer` updates it would  update to it's property. I have code like this

**Player.jsx**

```
const Player = ({ spotifyAPI }) => {
    const { spotifyPlayer, setSpotifyPlayer, playerInstance } = useContext(SpotifyPlayerContext)
    const [localPosition, setLocalPosition] = useState()
    const [isLocalPositionInterval, setIsLocalPositionInterval] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!spotifyPlayer) return
        if (!spotifyPlayer.playback) spotifyAPI.transferMyPlayback([spotifyPlayer.device_id])

        console.log("outside inteval", spotifyPlayer?.playback?.paused) // shows TRUE or FALSE, depending on state
        if (spotifyPlayer.playback && !isLocalPositionInterval) {
            console.log("fires only once")
            setIsLocalPositionInterval(true)
            const i = setInterval(() => {
                console.log("inside interval", spotifyPlayer.playback.paused) // it always shows TRUE
                setLocalPosition((prev) => (prev += spotifyPlayer.playback.paused ? 0 : 300)) // so this never increments
            }, 300)
        }
        setLocalPosition(spotifyPlayer?.playback?.position)
    }, [spotifyPlayer])
}
```

And the problem is that inside the interval function the `spotifyPlayer.playback.paused` is **always** TRUE, when outside it's depending on the state TRUE **or** FALSE. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz working demo for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I figure `spotifyPlayer` got inlined, so it doesn't reflect the latest change.
The whole construct is probably is bit borked:

- I guess `spotifyPlayer` is the identical object all the time. So when its values change, `useEffect` won't get called again (I don't know for sure b/c I don't know how it's getting created). So at all places where you check its values inside the `useEffect` callback will starve/not receive updates. Instead, your dependencies should be `[spotifyPlayer != null, spotifyPlayer.playback != null, spotifyPlayer?.device_id, spotifyPlayer?.playback.paused, isLocalPositionInterval, spotifyPlayer?.playback?.position]`. Note also that all of these are primitives - object don't work here and shouldn't be used in dependencies (if you don't know what you're doing)!
- You must `return () => clearInterval(i)` so the interval will be stopped on re-rendering - otherwise the interval timers will stack.

Even after alles these required fixes `spotifyPlayer.playback.pause` won't change in `setInterval`, though. Instead, you've got to create a new timer whenever `spotifyPlayer.playback.pause` changes, inlining the latest value of `spotifyPlayer.playback.pause`.

So long story short, you can't utilize an interval, but should go with `setTimer` instead and create a new one each time. It might even make sense to split the `useEffect` b/c not everything needs to get recreated anew for all dependency changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!spotifyPlayer) return;
  if (!spotifyPlayer.playback) spotifyAPI.transferMyPlayback([spotifyPlayer.device_id]);
}, [spotifyPlayer != null, spotifyPlayer.playback != null, spotifyPlayer?.device_id]);
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('outside inteval', spotifyPlayer?.playback?.paused); // shows TRUE or FALSE, depending on state
    let t: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>; // remove tha in case of plain TypeScript
    if (spotifyPlayer.playback && !isLocalPositionInterval) {
      console.log('fires only once');
      setIsLocalPositionInterval(true);
      t = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('inside interval', spotifyPlayer.playback.paused);
        setLocalPosition((prev) => (prev += spotifyPlayer.playback.paused ? 0 : 300));
      }, 300);
    }
    setLocalPosition(spotifyPlayer?.playback?.position);
    return () => {
      if (t) clearTimeout(t); // stop timer in case of unmounting!
    };
  }, [spotifyPlayer?.playback = null, spotifyPlayer?.playback?.paused, spotifyPlayer?.playback?.position, isLocalPositionInterval],
);
```

In general, I'ld advise to do some research about inlining, and about how `useEffect` dependencies work (and don't work).